# Error when encoding Base64 string via datasnap server

Tags: delphi-10.1-berlin, datasnap

A datasnap server method that returns base64 string gives me an error when I test it on a pdf file. Other pdf files work correctly, only difference is this pdf file is quite larger than the others - 78MB.

**HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error**

SERVER:

```
function TdmData.GetJobDocumentFile: string;
var fp : string;
begin
 Result := Emptystr;

 with fdQuery1 do
 begin
  Close;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Text := ' select doc_filename from DBA.documents';
  Open;
  fp := fieldbyname('doc_filename').asString;
  Close;
  UnPrepare;
 end;

 if (fp <> Emptystr) and FileExists(fp) then
 begin     
  Result := EncodeFile(fp); 
 end;
end;


function TdmData.EncodeFile(const FileName: string): AnsiString;
var Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
 Result := EmptyAnsiStr;
 Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;

 try
  Stream.LoadFromFile(Filename);
  Result := EncodeBase64(stream.Memory, stream.Size);

 finally
  Stream.Free;
 end;
end;


function TServerMethods1.GetDocumentFile : string;
begin
 try
  Result := dmData.GetJobDocumentFiledata;

 finally
  GetInvocationMetadata.CloseSession := True;
 end;
end;
```

CLIENT:

```
function TdmData.GetJobDocumentFileData: string;
var ServerMethods1Client : TServerMethods1Client;
begin
 ServerMethods1Client := nil;

 ServerMethods1Client := TServerMethods1Client.Create(DSRestConnection1);

 try
  Result := ServerMethods1Client.GetJobDocumentFileData;

 finally   
  ServerMethods1Client.Free;
  ServerMethods1Client := nil;
 end;
end;
```

Am I missing something here? Are there limitations when sending/receiving large strings via datasnap?

Any additional information would be great, thanks.

Comment: Base64 inflates data by 3/2 times. So your encoded PDF file will be 117 MB when transmitted. You are probably hitting some memory limit in Datasnap or the client.